# I don't understand the syntax to inherit a wpf user control

Tags: wpf

I have read multiple posts on the subject but still cannot manage to make it work.

I want 2 user controls slidertype1 and slidertype2 which should inherit from slidercommontype, all are in same namespacecommon, can someone knows the syntax for this simple use case ?

Inspiring from http://jamescrisp.org/2008/05/26/wpf-control-inheritance-with-generics/

I tried:

```
<namespacecommon:slidercommontype x:Class="namespacecommon.slidertype1">
```

but I got namespacecommon:slidercommontyp doesn't exist in xml namespace.

Comment: What syntax have you tried so far that isn't working? And what language—C# or VB.NET?

Comment: I have updated see above thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the base class doesn't have a XAML file associated with it, it's pretty easy. Trying to incorporate the visual aspect of the user control using XAML is not really a supported scenario.

Having said that, just create your class SliderCommonType (although I would call it SliderBase or something.)

```
namespace MyControls {
    public class SliderBase : UserControl {
    }
}
```

Then create your two controls based on it. I'll show one example and the other should be obvious.

```
<Local:SliderBase x:Class="MyControls.SliderType1"
                  xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyControls">
</Local:SliderBase>
```

And the code-behind would look like this:

```
namespace MyControls {
    public class SliderType1 : SliderBase {
    }
}
```

The key point being that your XAML file has to reference the base class which requires changing the `<UserControl>` element to `<Local:SliderBase>` which in turn requires a XAML namespace import.

When you add a UserControl using the default template, you can just change the code it creates to reflect the above changes. It's much easier than trying to create it from scratch.

One last thing to note - you will need your application to compile successfully before you can use the visual designer on your derived controls. This is because the designer needs to be able to instantiate SliderBase at design-time.